# pinecone problem with fetching example_upsert.json

Tags: vector

I have a problem with fetching `example_upsert.json`. How do I upsert it?

- `example_upsert.json`: https://dsh.re/725a96
- When I fetch it using the admin panel or `curl https://xxx.pinecone.io/vectors/fetch?ids=item_0`, I receive the following:

```
{
    "vectors": {},
    "namespace": ""
}
```

But when I upsert the default record using the admin panel -> upsert -> json editor - https://dsh.re/594a1d - and I fetch it using the admin panel or `curl https://xxx.pinecone.io/vectors/fetch?ids=id`, I receive the correct data.

Can anyone provide an example of why fetching `item_0` isn't working, but `id` is?